# x-axis spacing with log base 2 scale + rendering angstrom unit on the x-axis

Tags: matplotlib, logging

i have got a simple data set, which I need its x-axis values to be on a log base 2 scale. in addition, I used to type \Delta \angstrom or any mathematical expression as I would in LaTeX and the unit gets printed, It does not seem to work for me this time. any idea why?

my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    



x = [0.35,0.38,0.47,0.53,0.6,0.7,0.84,1.53]

y = [0,0.36,0.87,2.84,7.58,11.25,14.33,19.64]
    

plt.plot(x, y)
    

plt.xlabel(r'Grid spacing [\angstrom]')

plt.ylabel(r'% error')


plt.title('x-y plot')
    

plt.show()
```

I would like to have my plot like the one below, notice the line is flipped, I tried inverting my x and y values but did not work:

[image: wished plot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0.35,0.38,0.47,0.53,0.6,0.7,0.84,1.53]
y = [0,0.36,0.87,2.84,7.58,11.25,14.33,19.64]

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel(r'Grid spacing $\Delta\AA$')
plt.ylabel(r'% error')
plt.title('x-y plot')
plt.xscale('log', base=2)
plt.gca().invert_xaxis()  # To invert the x axis
plt.show()
```

I supplied `base` to the `xscale` function to specify a base-2 log, and I changed your usage of `\angstrom` to `\AA`.

Comment: the angstrom issue is solved, please see the question again, I edited it with an example of the wished plot

Comment: I've updated by response with the inverted x axis. Don't forget to accept my answer if it satisfied your question.

Comment: thanks, i accepted your answer. @K.Cl